# compileDebugJavaWithJavac error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I'm searching for a solution for the following error but couldn't solve it.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEfSc.png)

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mykSa.png)

Comment: Post your build.gradle file.

Comment: checkout my build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

To

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
```